# Fix the camera to a distance from a spritenode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, game-development

I am trying to fix the camera to a sprite node “players.first!” and I managed to do so using SKConstraints as follows

```
func setupWorld(){
    let playerCamera = SKCameraNode()
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: platformType + "BG")
    var cameraFollow = [SKConstraint]()
    cameraFollow.append(SKConstraint.distance(SKRange(constantValue: 0), to: players.first!))
    playerCamera.constraints = cameraFollow
    background.zPosition = layers().backgroundLayer
    background.constraints = cameraFollow
    background.size = self.size
    self.addChild(playerCamera)
    self.camera = playerCamera
    self.addChild(background)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    addEmitter()
}
```

But this keeps the camera fixed to the exact location of the node, I want the camera to be shifted to the right of the node “players.first!” (only in X dimension) and I couldn’t manage to do so with SKConstraints, note that the node is moving fast so updating the position of the camera in the update function makes the camera jitter.

[This image is explaining my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q9WE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Constrain the camera to an empty `SKNode` and make it a child node of the first player which is offset to the right in the frame of the player. This can be accomplished in the scene editor or programmatically by setting this dummy node's position to something like `CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0)`. When the player moves, this node will also move, dragging the camera along with it; and since the camera is focused on this node, the nodes in the same 'world' of the player will appropriately appear to move in the opposite direction while maintaining the look you want for the player.

EDIT: **If the player rotates**

If the player needs to rotate, the above configuration will result in the entire node world revolving around the fixed empty node. To prevent this, instead place an empty `SKNode` that acts as the fixed camera point  which will be called `"cameraLocation"` and the player node into another empty `SKNode` which will be called `"pseudoPlayer"`. Constrain the camera to `"cameraLocation"`.  Moving the `"pseudoPlayer"` node will then  move both the camera's fixed point (so that the camera moves) and the player node while only resulting in the rotation of the player and not the entire world.

NOTE: The only potential drawback is that in order to move the player correctly through the world, you must move the `"pseudoPlayer"` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately didn't work fine for me since my player node is rotating, which forces the new empty node to orbit around it, tried giving it a physicsbody and disable it's rotation but for somereason it freezes in the air and doesn't follow the player node position